# Google Forms / Google Sheets Remove Options Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have searched through a number of other answers but haven't quite been able to find a solution. I have a Google Form, which customers use to sign up for volunteer spots on a weekly basis. We fill out all the weeks for the year so customers can go through and sign up for the various weeks they are interested in. Looking for a script that could reference the answers in the linked Google sheet to change the questions on the form.

So if we have

- April 10th
- April 17th
- April 24th

in the list of options on google forms (and our cap is 6 people signed up), if April 10th has 4 people, April 17th has 6 people and April 24th has 1 person, the script would remove the April 17th question from Google forms. I have a count forumla on the Google sheets that sums the total people signed up for each day, so it is a simple range of single reference cells for each corresponding day in the list.

[image: Google Form setup]
[image: Google Sheets data page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script should look something like this:

#### Code:

```
var ssID = '1kmVW8fbHnRIwcJawPlTJ-hWHNnMuVovtqbsCinTKTKw';
var formID = '1z5kPkGAg9e7K7T5NMKBfa9J9mmx6hNVBBjL5hwPcOOo';
var wsData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("data");
var form = FormApp.openById(formID);
var options = ["1 person", "2 person", "3 person", "4 person"];

function main() {
  // get list of responses directly from form instead of sheets
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  // get list of date questions
  var dates = wsData.getRange(2, 1, wsData.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().filter(Boolean);
  var counts = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
    var formResponse = formResponses[i];
    var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
    for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
      var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
      var question = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
      // count only answers for date questions
      if (dates.includes(question)) {
        var answer = parseInt(itemResponse.getResponse().replace(' person',''));
        counts[question] = counts[question] ? counts[question] + answer : answer;
      }
    }
  }
  // get list of questions
  var items = form.getItems();
  var titles = items.map(function (item) {
    return item.getTitle();
  });

  dates = dates.forEach(function (date, index){
    // get position of each date question
    var pos = titles.indexOf(date)
    if (pos !== -1) {
      // get id
      var item = items[pos];
      var itemID = item.getId();
      var item = form.getItemById(itemID);
      // count remaining slots
      var slots = 6 - counts[date];
      // if all slots are already used, remove question
      if(slots == 0) {
        form.deleteItem(item);
      }
      else {
        // set new options up to remaining slots
        var newOptions = options.slice(0, slots);
        item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(newOptions);
      }
      // assign slots used in sheets
      wsData.getRange(index + 2, 2).setValue(counts[date]);
    }
  });
}
```

#### data sheet:

[image: data]

#### Form:

[image: form]

#### Note:

- Make sure to install `onFormSubmit` trigger for function `main`
- What this do is when the form is filled up and submitted, it triggers this function.
- Every form submission should be submitted once, avoid using "Submit another response" as it will use the non-updated form.
- This reads the responses using `getResponses` instead of reading response sheet
- This will remove the item if there are no remaining slots

Comment: Ok I think I am nearly there, 2 things. 1 - my google forms dates are each their own individual question, does that matter for this script ability to remove? 2. On my data sheet, I have a column beside each date option (which is each an individual question on the google form) which has the total people registered for each date. I imagine I need to change the script to simply look at the 2nd column cell corresponding to each date and simply see if the total equals 6 or not instead of the count function (which would be looking to count every time it sees a duplicate date?)

Comment: Hi @dwilliams, Unless I am able to visualize the sheet and form, it is kind of hard to understand the things you just noted down. Can you try and show them in your original post?

Comment: Hi @NaziA - I added pictures to the original post.

Comment: hi @dwilliams, I'd like to clarify, are the options per date somewhat like "join" and "not join"? so you like to remove the question instead of an option? I understood your original post as removing an **OPTION** (I assume, one of the choices of a question) not an **ITEM/QUESTION** (that asks if you join or not).

Comment: each date is the question, with a drop down for signups for that event (options on dropdown are 1 person, 2 person, 3 person, 4 person). Not a simple yes no. So customers fill out a couple questions at the beginning (name, email, etc) and then select which days they want to sign up for and how many people they want to sign up.

Comment: So you want it applied to all questions and all options then? Hmmm, this seems very time consuming. I'll try my best to try and work it out. @dwilliams

Comment: hi @dwilliams, I have now updated my answer. Please do read the comments in the script to follow what it does. There have been changes to the approach so hopefully you can still follow. If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Got this error:                                                                                                    11:05:54 AM Error 
Exception: Array is empty: values
(anonymous) @ Code.js.gs:49       item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(newOptions);
main @ Code.js.gs:32             dates = dates.forEach(function (date, index){

Comment: copy paste the specific line. @dwilliams. If you're talking about `setChoiceValues`, that points to the slots being empty thus `slice` returns blank array. and `setChoiceValues` needs not to be blanked. but that should be caught by the condition `if (slots == 0)`. Have you tried debugging? Any tests you've done that points to what causes the issue?

Comment: Line 49 from error is - item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(newOptions);

Comment: Line 32 from error is - dates = dates.forEach(function (date, index){

Comment: This was from running in debug mode

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231618/room-for-nazia-and-dwilliams please join @dwilliams, let's continue our discussion in the chat room

Comment: Figured out the issue thanks to @NaziA . Had 1 extra say in the list in my data sheet which did not match the list at present on the google form. Now it all works!

Comment: Glad it worked out. Thank you for being patient @dwilliams. Good luck